# Text-only CSS slideshow

Tags: html, css, animation, slideshow, css-animations

I am trying to create a CSS-only slideshow for text content.

I have this HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CSS text slideshow</title>
        <style>
        #slideshow
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .item
        {
            position: absolute;
            max-width: 500px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .item:nth-child(1)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 30s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 30s infinite;
        }
        .item:nth-child(2)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 24s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 24s infinite;
        }
        .item:nth-child(3)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 18s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 18s infinite;
        }
        .item:nth-child(4)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 12s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 12s infinite;
        }
        .item:nth-child(5)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 6s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 6s infinite;
        }
        .item:nth-child(6)
        {
            -webkit-animation: crossfade 48s 0s infinite;
            animation: crossfade 48s 0s infinite;
        }
        @keyframes crossfade
        {
            0%
            {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            10.5%
            {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            12.5%
            {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            98%
            {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100%
            {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='slideshow'>
            <div class='item'>
                One
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                Two
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                Three
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                Four
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                Five
            </div>
            <div class='item'>
                Six
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the slideshow never starts. The nth-child selector is correctly applied to all `item`s but they remain at `opacity: 0`.

How can I get the slideshow to start automatically?

EDIT: This appears to be working in Firefox, but not Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I copied your whole code to JSBin and the slideshow is running.. https://jsbin.com/teqarusabo/edit?html,output what else is your problem?

Comment: @RohitKumar I'm not seeing anything on JSBin in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: well, I'm seeing in my mozilla firefox, the counter is running like - Six, Five, Four... with fading effects

Comment: @RohitKumar Firefox works for me too, I assume because it supports the `animation` property without a prefix. I assume then that IE also works since it also supports the property (I only have OS X so can't check). Chrome and Safari do not work, however. They both require the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: have you added -webkit- prefix to the keyframes also?? in your original code? that's why it isn't working in chrome..

Comment: @RohitKumar No. This was the problem - thank you. I'll create a new answer & credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-webkit-` prefix to the `keyframes` also, like this

```
@-webkit-keyframes {
 /* rest other code goes here */
}
```